# Как можно поставить значок корзины в шапку

Tags: header

Как можно поставить значок корзины в шапку сайта на мобильном версии?
Попробуйте зайти через мобильной idealstroy.kg на правом верхнем углу надо поставить значок корзинки

Comment: Ссылки на сайт в вопросе не годятся - потом у вас сайт изменится/закроется и будет не понятно что у вас не получалось. Приведите код/разметку/вёрстку нужного функционала прямо в вопросе текстом.

Answer (score 1):

В @media для нужной Вам ширины экрана поменяйте у .header-iconwrap свойство display на absolute и задайте нужные координаты.